# SQL Datepart Where Clause not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, asp-classic, ado

I am having a problem with the end of a complicated query:

```
SQLString = "SELECT i.CONCOM, 
                    COALESCE(SUM(CASE 
                                   WHEN C.CATEGORY_ID = '30' THEN 0 
                                   ELSE t.LOGMINS END), 0) AS TotalWithoutNew, 
                    COALESCE(SUM(t.LOGMINS), 0) AS TotalAllId 
               FROM Inquiry AS i 
         INNER JOIN TIMELOG AS t ON t.INQUIRY_ID = i.INQUIRY_ID 
         INNER JOIN PROD AS P ON i.PROD_ID = P.PROD_ID 
         INNER JOIN CATEGORY AS C ON P.CATEGORY_ID = C.CATEGORY_ID 
              WHERE (DATEPART(m, ESCDATE) = " & objmonth & ") 
                AND (DATEPART(y, ESCDATE) = " & objyear & ") 
           GROUP BY i.CONCOM 
           ORDER BY concom ASC"
```

The query works fine without the where clause but when I put the where clause in it returns nothing. `ESCDATE` is a DATETIME field. I thought at first it wasn't passing integers to it but strings, and it is definitely passing integers.

Further up in the ASP script I am using `Request.Querystring` to get a month and a year and I basically want to check against ESC date that it only brings results back from the month specified in the year specified.

Comment: If there's an index on `ESCDATE`, using `DATEPART` won't be able to use it.

Comment: You should use parameterised queries. If you are taking these values straight from `Request.Querystring` and concatenating them into the query you will get SQL injection issues.

Comment: To reinforce @martin's comment, the sql injection problem is kind of a big deal, and you shoudln't ignore it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'y' specifier is day of year, not year. Try 'yy' or 'yyyy' instead.